# How can i inform about google oauth to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0

I need your help.
I have an app. I can login with normal (email and password) and using Google Auth.

When i print my informations to console.log, it successfully prints, but I use firebase and i need to firebase.auth().onStateChanged for control the state.

For example, if i login with email and password, then onstateChanged function works with useEffect, and it redirect homepage (because this function know user has signed in), but when i login with google, i can't inform about user signed in or not because of google.

How can i use both google sign in and firebase? How can i tell firebase, i login with google, there are my informations don't worry.

Here google logs (my google name and googleId):
[image]

my codes:

google codes:

```
const GoogleAuth = () => {
  const saveFirebase = (email, uid) => {
    return firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(uid).set({
      email: email,
    });
  };

  const onSuccess = (response) => {
    const name = response.profileObj.name;
    const uid = response.profileObj.googleId;
    console.log(uid);
    console.log(name);

    return saveFirebase(name, uid);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    return (
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId="1093050194946-tcn6k22l190klav7cat182leq09luthu.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess={onSuccess}
        onFailure={onSuccess}
        cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
        theme="dark"
      />
    );
  };

  return <div className="google-button">{handleClick()}</div>;
};
```

my constant variables:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("");
```

onAuthStateChanged codes with useEffect:

```
 const authListener = () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        setUsername(user.displayName);
      } else {
        
      }
    });
  };

useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
  });
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question. Both authentications work as they should do you only don't know wich one of them the user used to login?

Comment: @TarikHuber Yes, i can login but both of them, but firebase auth state can't know is google sign in or not. I need to tell user signed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the user loged in with email or Google just use the `providerId` from `user` you get from the `onAuthStateChanged` like here:

```
 const authListener = () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        setUsername(user.displayName);

        //Here you can se what provider the user used 
        console.log('provider',user.providerId)
      } else {
        
      }
    });
  };
```